# How to prevent Azure DevOps machine agent from stopping the service?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a deployment group in Azure DevOps and registered an Azure Pipelines agent on a windows 2016 Server machine. After registering the machine, the service started successfully and the machined appeared as online in Azure DevOps. However, the service turned itself off after few hours and the agent was not discoverable after few hours as in the picture
[image]

I restarted the service (highlighted in yeloow) but the still the machine appears offline in Azure DevOps.

[image]

Can you please help?

Comment: You should check the logs on the agent in order to determine why the service stops. Logs can be found under `C:\agent\_diag` or `C:\agent\work\_diag` . You could also check Event Viewer to verify error codes/problems

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the issue could be caused by the deprecation of TLS1.0 / TLS 1.1.

According to [the blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-in-azure-devops/), per Microsoft’s position to protect against cryptographic attacks, we are announcing that Azure DevOps services will no longer accept connections coming over TLS 1.0 / TLS 1.1 and require TLS 1.2 at a minimum.

If your local machine is using TLS 1.0 / TLS 1.1, it can cause the agent keeping offline.

Refer to the following steps below to check and enable TLS 1.2 in your machine:

1. Run this script:[PowerShell script to check TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement#powershell-script-to-check-tls-12)  in your Powershell to check the current TLS 1.2 settings.

If you have enabled TLS 1.2 successfully, you are supposed to see the same result as the picture below:

[image]

If not, please follow Step 2 to enable TLS 1.2.

2. Run this Powershell script:[PowerShell script to enable TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement#powershell-script-to-enable-tls-12)  to enable TLS 1.2. After enabling TLS 1.2, please run the script in Step 1 to check and make sure you have enabled TLS 1.2 successfully. Please also kindly share a screenshot of the result with us.
3. After enabling TLS 1.2, you need to enable below cipher suites: (Please find the cipher suites here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-azure-devops-services/#how-to-enable-tls-1-2 )

Path:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\

Right-click on Ciphers and add a new key named
**TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (*)**, right-click on this key and add a DWORD value Enabled:00000001

It is key that on the OS one of the four TLS 1.2 cipher suites below is enabled:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (*)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (*)
```

4. Open Gpedit.msc (local group policy) and set the following Group policy: Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Network, SSL Configuration Settings > SSL Cipher Suite Order. Set the policy to enabled.
   (**Please make sure the required cipher exists here, otherwise the empty cipher will overwrite the cipher in the registry key.**)
5. Run “GPupdate.exe /force” in Admin mode.

[image]

6. Restart the local machine.
7. Check the connection by below command:
   (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri status.dev.azure.com).StatusDescription
   It returns OK means the connection between local machine and AzureDevOps is working well.